# How to populate text fields in a browser control

Tags: c#, web

I am programatically creating a web browser and using the documentcompleted event handler to populate some fields. however, one field takes user input and then another (label style) field displays the user input in a formatted way. If i use the SetAttribute method on this input field, the second field is not aware that the first field has been populated, and so it always appears blank.

Any ideas how i can populate the field in a way to get the second field to respond to the change?

Comment: Can you show us your code so far? are you using Javascript to detect the field1's text_changed and setting field2? in your C# code you could simply set the field2 = field1;

Comment: I think i found it. Jeremy's javascript comment got me thinking. It seems that i was reacting to the first DocumentComplete event, I didnt realise there was more than one. Once i trapped the correct document complete event, it started working. Cheers Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was more than one DocumentComplete event in the process. I should have waited until all documents had loaded.